# React - if statement displays else condition before showing the matching condition

Tags: reactjs

Running into an issue where I have an "if statement" that is displaying the else portion of the statement for about half a second before actually matching the first part of the statement. How can I get it to only display what it matches?

For example, the first part of the if statement and avoid ever showing the else condition of the if statement. In the case of the code below when the browser loads the component it shows "This is not a Technical report" for about half a second then it goes away and "This is a Technical report" appears. When done the other way the first part of the if statement never appears and only the else section appears. This issue only happens if the first condition matches. Code Below:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import axios from "axios";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";

function ViewReport(props) {

  if (Report.InterviewType === "Technical") {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>This is a Technical report</h1>
      </div>
    );
  } else {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>This is not a Technical report</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default ViewReport;
```

Comment: To solve this, you can add a loading state or return null, while the `Report.InterviewType` is empty.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because initially, it takes sometime to load `Report` object and as a result, `if` condition fails. Therefore, you can check whether `Report.InterviewType` does exist.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import axios from "axios";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";

function ViewReport(props) {

  if (Report.InterviewType === "Technical") {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>This is a Technical report</h1>
      </div>
    );
  } else if(Report.InterviewType) {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>This is not a Technical report</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default ViewReport;
```

In this case, I believe that initial value of `Report.InterviewType` is `undefined` or `null`. If it's not null, then you have to put the relevant initial value for `else if` check. Let's say the initial value is `x`, then it will be as follows.

```
else if(Report.InterviewType === x){ ... }
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Tried adding ````Report.InterviewType```` as you mentioned but then I received an error for no return since both conditions failed. However, you were correct it did have to do with the loading period while the API data is fetched. Probably my fault since I didnt provide the full code in the original question. Thanks for the advice its now working.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @kavinduvlndika and @junaidfaryad I was able to understand why the issue was occurring and I simply added an empty return as a third condition in the if statement. This allows a staging point while the API fetches the data.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import axios from "axios";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";

function ViewReport(props) {

  if (Report.InterviewType === "Technical") {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>This is a Technical Interview</h1>
      </div>
    );
  } else if (Report.InterviewType === "LeadershipPrinciples") {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>This is not a Technical Interview</h1>
      </div>
    );
  } else {
    return <div></div>;
  }
}
```